# Los datos de las instancias no se quedan guardados usando List<> en C#

Tags: c#, lista, class

Estoy trabajando con un programa que sirve para agregar empleados de diferentes tipos a una lista:

- Empleado de tiempo completo
- Empleado de medio tiempo
- Empleado temporero

Para lograr esto, creé una clase padre llamada **`Empleado`**, y luego tres clases diferentes con el nombre de los tipos de empleados previamente mencionados, estas clases heredan de la clase **`Empleado`** los atributos.

A cada una de las clases de tipos de empleados les agregué un metodo llamado `crearEmpleado()`, el cual cumple la funcion de pedir al usuario los datos del empleado que va a agregar en la lista, creando así instancias.

El objetivo es que cada vez que el usuario agregue un empleado a una lista estos se queden guardados mientras la consola siga abierta.

*Esta es una de las clases de los tipos de empleados:*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TAREA3
{
public class tiempo_completo:empleado
{
    public string metodo_pago = "Cuenta bancaria";
    public string tipo = "Empleado a tiempo completo";
    
    public override void Ponchar()
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Empleado #{0}, con nombre: {1} ha ponchado. \n" +
                          "Hora: {2}", codigo, nombre, date);
    }

    public override void Trabajar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("<{0}>, {1} está trabajando!", tipo, nombre);
    }

    public override void Cobrar()
    {
        double salario = precio_hora * horas_laboradas;
        Console.WriteLine("Tipo de empleado: {0} \n" +
                          "Salario: {1} \n" +
                          "Método de pago: {2}", tipo, salario, metodo_pago);
    }

    public void crearEmpleado()
    {
        List<tiempo_completo> TiempoCompleto = new  List<tiempo_completo>();
        Console.WriteLine("[EMPLEADO A TIEMPO COMPLETO]");
        int id = TiempoCompleto.Count;
        
        TiempoCompleto.Add(new tiempo_completo());
        TiempoCompleto[id].codigo = id;
        Console.WriteLine("El codigo de empleado asignado es: {0}", TiempoCompleto[id].codigo);
        Console.Write("INGRESE EL NOMBRE DE EMPLEADO: ");
        TiempoCompleto[id].nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("INGRESE EL DEPARTAMENTO: ");
        TiempoCompleto[id].departamento = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("INGRESE EL CARGO: ");
        TiempoCompleto[id].cargo = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE HORAS A LABORAR: ");
        TiempoCompleto[id].horas_laboradas = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("INGRESE EL PRECIO POR HORA: ");
        TiempoCompleto[id].precio_hora = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                
        Console.WriteLine();
                
        Console.WriteLine("[AQUI SE IMPRIMIRAN LOS METODOS]");

        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------");
        TiempoCompleto[id].Ponchar();
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------");
        TiempoCompleto[id].Trabajar();
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------");
        TiempoCompleto[id].Cobrar();
       
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad total de empleados en la lista es: {0}", TiempoCompleto.Count);
    }
    
    
}
}
```

***Este es el codigo de la clase program*** en donde llamo los metodos de las diferentes clases, pues tengo un *bucle while* en cada `case`, el cual le pide al usuario que escriba 1 para volver a crear otro empleado pero lo que sucede es que al llamar el metodo `Main()` todo se borra y los datos no se quedan en la lista, lo cual es extraño ya que las listas no estan creadas en la clase Program, es decir, que si no estan en la clase principal esos datos debieran quedarse guardados al momento de llamar al metodo `Main()`

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace TAREA3
    {
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int switchNumber;
            Console.WriteLine("[BIENVENIDO A CREA-EMPLEADOS]");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("1. EMPLEADO A TIEMPO COMPLETO \n" +
                              "2. EMPLEADO A MEDIO TIEMPO \n" +
                              "3. EMPLEADO TEMPORERO");
            switchNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (switchNumber)
            {
                case 1 :
                    tiempo_completo empleadoTiempoCompleto = new tiempo_completo();
                    empleadoTiempoCompleto.crearEmpleado();
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("1. AGREGAR OTRO EMPLEADO");
                    switchNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    while (switchNumber == 1)
                    {
                        Main(new string[] { });
                    }
                    
                    break;
                
                case 2 :
                    medio_tiempo empleadoMedioTiempo = new medio_tiempo();
                    empleadoMedioTiempo.crearEmpleado();
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("1. AGREGAR OTRO EMPLEADO");
                    switchNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    while (switchNumber == 1)
                    {
                        Main(new string[] { });
                    }
                    break;
                
                case 3 :
                    temporero empleadoTemporero = new temporero();
                    empleadoTemporero.crearEmpleado();
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("1. AGREGAR OTRO EMPLEADO");
                    switchNumber = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    while (switchNumber == 1)
                    {
                        Main(new string[] { });
                    }
                    break;
                
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Cada vez que llamas al método `crearEmpleado()`, la primera línea de código que aparece `List<tiempo_completo> TiempoCompleto = new  List<tiempo_completo>();`, hace que borre todos los datos, es como si la crearas nuevamente.

Comment: Otra sugerencia es que tengas en cuenta la delegación de responsabilidades de clases en la Programación Orientada a Objeto

Comment: hola, podrias hacerme saber si la solucion propuesta te sirvio

Comment: Si, me sirvió, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cada vez que vas a añadir un empleado, estás instanciando nuevamente la lista, para evitar ese problema debes sacar la instanciación de tu método para no vaciar tu `List<T>` cada vez que creas un Empleado. Deberías colocar tu `List<Empleado>` en tu `Main`.

Sería:

```
var listaEmpleado = new List<Empleado>();
```

Y entonces tú método quedaría:

```
public void CrearEmpleado(List<Empleado> lista)
{
    lista.Add(new() EmpleadoX);
}
```